# d3.js plotting population on a map

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

so I am working on a d3.js project where I am mapping the population of individual countries on a map using a circle, and the size of the circle increases based on number (obviously). I have a .csv file with the longitude and latitude of each country aswell as the population. This is my code:

*UPDATE* When console.log(pop_data) is called it is returning the values of population as a string, could this be the issue? if so how to i resolve this.

```
d3.csv("data/population.csv", function(pop_data) {
                            console.log(pop_data);

                            svg.selectAll("circle")
                                .data(pop_data)
                                .enter()
                                .append("circle")
                                .attr("cx", function(d){
                                    return projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[0];
                                })
                                .attr("cy", function(d) {
                                    return projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[1];
                                })
                                .attr("r", function(d) {
                                    return Math.sqrt(parseInt(d.populations) * 10);
                                })
                                .style("fill", "black")
                                .style("stroke", "grey")
                                .style("stroke-width", 0.25)
                                .style("opacity", 0.75);
                    });
```

but for some reason it is returning this error:

d3.js:1382 Error:  attribute r: Expected length, "NaN".

Anyone have any suggestions as to why this is happening? Baring in mind in my csv file the longitude is called longitude, latitude is called latitude and population is called populations.

Comment: What shows if you use `.attr("r", function(d) { console.log(d.populations); return 1; })`

Comment: @AndrewReid it returns the population but as a number

Comment: @AndrewReid it is also now plotting the circles in the correct places however they are all the same size

Comment: That's the return 1; as for logging, if you got a number each time for d.populations I'm a little stumped.

Comment: @AndrewReid as in it is jsut logging the populations as they are written is this not correct?

Comment: Sometimes a single value might trip up the drawing of circles, it's nice to confirm that you are getting numbers (and also good to confirm they draw if a hard coded number is provided). While it might not do any good, you could try logging `Math.sqrt(parseInt(d.populations) * 10)`.

Comment: @AndrewReid okay, so its quite intersting whats happened now, when i log that it displays all the number perfectly, from start to finish, but then after it logs 46 NaN's, as if theres something hidden?

Comment: Are there blank lines at the base of the csv? Do you have a copy you can potentially share?

Comment: @AndrewReid problem solved! I literally just copied the contents of the csv into a new csv file and it removed the mistake! thanks for all your help

Comment: Glad it's working - I wonder what was off with the original csv